# Need help identifying the 'override method' pattern used in this code

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, software-design

The following is a simplification from a project I am working on.

We have `Talker niceTalker` who says *"Good morning! My name is Joe"*. 
Then we have a schitzophrenic `rudeTalker`, who says *"He is me"*.

It took me a while to understand what the code does.
To me, this seems an awfully complicated way of overriding `Talker`s `talk()` method.
Furher more, `TalkModifier` is used as a command in [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (not shown).

Why take this approach, instead of say polymorphism through inheritance? Is this a known pattern, which one?

```
public interface Talker {
    String getName();
    void talk();
}
```

-

```
public interface TalkModifier {
    public Talker modify(Talker talker);
}
```

-

```
class NiceGuy implements Talker {
    @Override
    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("Good morning! My name is " + getName() +".");
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Joe";
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Talker niceTalker = new NiceGuy();

        TalkModifier rudeTalker = new TalkModifier() {
            public Talker modify(final Talker talker) {
                return new Talker() {
                    @Override
                    public void talk() {
                        System.out.println("He is me.");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getName() {
                        return talker.getName();
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        niceTalker.talk();
        System.out.println();
        rudeTalker.modify(niceTalker).talk();   
    }
}
```

Comment: One possible advantage I could see here is that you could run a talker object through several different modifiers to fine tune it's behavior. That might be better than a simple inheritance tree for complicated behaviors, but I am unsure why you would use this over say, the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: @clearlyspam23 Might it be a better approach if the `Talker` is thought of as a command used with the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). A command which is passed around between different objects each of which would fine tune it, execute it and then pass it along?

Comment: @Pétur it's hard for me to say without the full context. The design used here looks like it's more in the style of functional programming languages. I suppose as another advantage here, each time you run the object through a modifier you are returning an entirely new object, which might help limit side effects (although this benefit is still somewhat limited, as you are in effect storing an instance of the older object in each new object).

Comment: @clearlyspam23 Storing the instance of the old command, within, is useful should there be need to undo the command at a later point. My code does not take this into account by providing access to the original object.

Comment: @Pétur actually, upon further investigation I believe this code might be employing aspects of the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Software Engineering, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TylerH Seconded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a combination of two patterns:

- [*Delegation pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) - This pattern is implemented by the class created inside `TalkModifier`'s `modify` method, and
- [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) - This pattern is implemented by `TalkModifier` anonymous implementation (`TalkModifier` is essentially a factory interface)

A slight twist is that both patterns are implemented using anonymous classes, with a method of one anonymous class producing objects of another anonymous class.

Comment: Is there a benefit to this approach? Might this be a straight forward implementation seen from the perspective of a programmer coming from a different language?

Comment: How can `TalkModifier`'s `modify` method can be `Delegation`..?

Comment: @Ramesh-X It's not the `modify` method itself, it's the anonymous class that it creates on the `return new Talker() { ... }` line. It is this anonymous class that delegates the call of `getName()` to `final talker` object.

Comment: @Pétur The biggest benefit to doing it this way is hiding the implementation completely - both from the callers (because all they see is interfaces) and from your own library, because anonymous classes do not "pollute" library's namespace. Another side benefit is deferral of wrapper creation to the moment of call to `modify`, which can be used to fetch some additional state (your code is not doing it, though).